# SQL Trigger errors

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `table_insert` AFTER INSERT ON  `user` 
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN 
INSERT INTO 
VALUES log (username,action)

NEW.name, 'successful addition'

);

END ;
```

I'm just looking to experiment with triggers but i get many errors no matter what I do, when i Try and work it I might get an error like so:

SUPER privilege needed for this operation

Check syntax

Could some1 who has any knowledge please show me how to add a trigger?

I am using PHPmyAdmin to work on my mysql database hosted on a blacknight server.

Comment: Do you have privlage to perform all.the actions you are performing??

Answer (score 0):

Is new.name  --> name correct column? or username?

```
       IF not:

  Insert  into  log(username,action)
  values(
  new.name,
  'successful addition'
  )
```

Comment: I've changed the query and it only comes up with need SUPER privileges to run this operation, have looked this up online and seems to be a common problem, am i able to get the SUPER privs if the db is hosted by another company>

Comment: Are you using main user(which they gave to you)? If yes you just  can't grant more privilegies to yourself.  I think you have this privilegie but... what error are you getting?

Comment: #1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation

Comment: Just contact to that hosting company and tell them about this...  Error is in privileges, not in query as you said so...

Comment: Seems that because I'm on a certain plan I cannot have super privs, would have to upgrade and I can't afford this, is there any alternatives to triggers that I could potential use?